# IBM Worklight - How do I tell the Worklight Environment wizard what Android API level to use?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I have a fresh install of Eclipse 4.3, Worklight Studio v6.1 Consumer Edition, Worklight Mobile Test Workbench, Android SDK and the ADT plug-in. I am using Windows 7. Using the Android SDK, I only installed the Android 19 API. In Eclipse Window -> Preferences -> Android, the SDK Location is correct and the list shows 3 targets - all using Android 19 ("Android 4.4.2", "Google APIs" and "Google APIs x86").

When I use the wizard to create an Android Worklight Environment, it insists on using the Android 18 API level. I know I can change the API level using the Properties of the created Android project but I should not have to. I have seen other questions where the wizard used Android 19 and they wanted to use a lower level. But the answers did not mention a way to permanently change that.

I also noticed that the created iml file had this line:

```
<orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="Android 4.2.2" jdkType="Android SDK" />
```

Android 4.2.2 is associated with the Android 17 API which adds even more confusion.

I cannot find anywhere to specify which API level to use. Is there a place to do this? Or will I always have to change my created Android projects? It seems others are getting projects created with Android 19 so why am I seeing it use Android 18?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Worklight 6.1.0.x, when adding the Android environment to an application, its AndroidManifest.xml will initially be created with `android:targetSdkVersion="18"`.

18 is the default value generated by Worklight Studio until upped to 19 or otherwise in a future release.
You cannot change this behavior (only after it is generated, you can manually change it to 19).

Comment: I expected that it was a default value used by the wizard. But, it seems rather odd that there is no way to override this. Seems like the wizard could include the ability to select the target from a list of known SDK targets. Not a big deal but definitely confusing for someone just starting out with Worklight Studio.

Comment: You can submit requests for enhancements via: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/connect.html --- if my answer helped clarify your issue please mark as Answered.